# download excel with an hyperlink in html

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to download the excel from the angular application, as part of that I have created a subfolder called `Files`

```
<p><a href="/Files/MyList.xlsx" download target="_self"> Click to Download </a></p>
```

By using the above code, when I click on hyperlink  one file is getting downloaded and showing error like `Failed- No file`.

I have read many issues in SO, in all the issues the solution is putting the file into the folder and downloading, in the same way I have done, created the Files folder and and kepy my file there, still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you check the spelling? Including capitalization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="https://www.smartsheet.com/file/ic-project-timeline-template-8857xlsx" >Download Excel Template</a>
```

I have done like this | i didnt faced any problems | and the problem is completely in your xls file only .......

Comment: Seems yes, looks like my excel issue it is, I kept it in my server and it is downloading